# iPhone XS not being recognized properly in Android Studio for Flutter App

Tags: android-studio, flutter, iphone-x, libimobiledevice

I just received an iPhone XS for development, and I'm running into an issue using it to run my Flutter App in Android Studio.

When I plug in my old iPhone 6s, Android Studio **[shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heCDq.png)**, just the normal name of the iPhone.

But when I plug my XS in, it **[shows this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMPQd.png)** a huge string that looks like it's showing the command line tools for ideviceinfo. This is also causes an error when trying to install the app:

```
Installing and launching...
error: module importing failed: ('invalid syntax', ('temp.py', 1, 27, 'import fruitstrap_00008020-001C50503488002E\n'))
backtrace unavailable
```

Oddly enough, **I can still run the app in Xcode.** So I'm assuming this is an Android Studio bug that hasn't been worked out yet. Anyone run into anything like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new iPhones use a new UDID format which libimobiledevice doesn't support yet. The tools crash and that causes the output you see.

You'll need to wait for a new version of libimobiledevice to become available which supports the new UDID format.

Some folks [have submitted a PR](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/pull/705) but it hasn't been merged yet.

Comment: This is it! If anyone wants to keep up with this:
https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/pull/703
https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller/pull/102
https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy/pull/360
I think the only one we are still waiting on is iOS-deploy.